# Seeking a lightweight C/C++ stats library that will do time series analysis and forecasting (ARIMA, etc)

Tags: c++, c, statistics

Working here in an embedded Linux scenario. I'm wondering if someone could identify or point me to a **C/C++ statistical library** that does time series analysis (including ARMA and ARIMA, decomposition, etc).

My wishlist (search criteria):

Lightweight (ie, small, not resource intensive)
Open source / freeware
Mainstream or some sort of certification so that I can convince mgrs to use it.
Thanks in advance!